# how to upload path in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CI. Currently I have the following:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

I just want to know how to update path in codeignitor. I have tried the below code. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH')`enter code here` OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Upload extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        }

        function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }

        function do_upload()
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';

            $this->load->library('Upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: question is not celar..

Comment: where is image name?

Comment: $this->upload->do_upload('userfile') and Upload to change upload

Comment: There's no question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Your code Your file will be uploaded at **uploads** **folder** which is in your root directory. `$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';` this is the place where your  uploaded  files are stored.
You make an directory **uploads** there where an application folder is .
If you want your current code.

You'll need a destination folder for your uploaded images. Create a folder at the root of your CodeIgniter installation called uploads and set its file permissions to 777.
By default the upload routine expects the file to come from a form field called userfile.
from [file uploading class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this library to upload... Its easy to use

http://demo.codesamplez.com/codeigniter/file-upload-demo

View

```
 <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
Select File To Upload:<br />
<input type="file" name="userfile" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>

{if isset($uploaded_file)}
{foreach from=$uploaded_file key=name item=value}
{$name} : {$value}
<br />
{/foreach}
{/if}
```

Controller

```
/**
* the demo for file upload tutorial on codesamplez.com
* @return view
*/
public function file_upload_demo()
{
try
{
if($this->input->post("submit")){
$this->load->library("app/uploader");
$this->uploader->do_upload();
}
return $this->view();
}
catch(Exception $err)
{
log_message("error",$err->getMessage());
return show_error($err->getMessage());
}
}
```

Component

```
/**
* Description of uploader
*
* @author Rana
*/
class Uploader {
var $config;
public function __construct() {
$this->ci =& get_instance();
$this->config = array(
'upload_path' => dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])."/files/",
'upload_url' => base_url()."files/",
'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|xml",
'overwrite' => TRUE,
'max_size' => "1000KB",
'max_height' => "768",
'max_width' => "1024"
);
}
public function do_upload(){
$this->remove_dir($this->config["upload_path"], false);
$this->ci->load->library('upload', $this->config);
if($this->ci->upload->do_upload())
{
$this->ci->data['status']->message = "File Uploaded Successfully";
$this->ci->data['status']->success = TRUE;
$this->ci->data["uploaded_file"] = $this->ci->upload->data();
}
else
{
$this->ci->data['status']->message = $this->ci->upload->display_errors();
$this->ci->data['status']->success = FALSE;
}
}
function remove_dir($dir, $DeleteMe) {
if(!$dh = @opendir($dir)) return;
while (false !== ($obj = readdir($dh))) {
if($obj=='.' || $obj=='..') continue;
if (!@unlink($dir.'/'.$obj)) $this->remove_dir($dir.'/'.$obj, true);
}

closedir($dh);
if ($DeleteMe){
@rmdir($dir);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image name'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
```